# return name of object from class

Tags: python, string, class, return

how to return the name of the object-

```
class sampleclass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        return self

dogfood = sampleclass

print(dogfood)

outputs this : 
class '__main__.sampleclass'
```

..Trying to output dogfood

Comment: An object doesn't have access to the name of the variable it's bound to

Answer (score 0):

Reading the variable name is not possible easily.
You could instead use some kind of key-value store (dictionary). Then you can read out the name of the key under that a value is stored.

Answer (score 0):

[Attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) are one way to store a custom name string inside an object that can be retrieved later:

```
class sampleclass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return self

sample_object = sampleclass('dogfood')

print(sample_object.name)
# Output: 'dogfood'
```